# put a dictionary outside of a function and inside of a function make differences for time complexity

Tags: python, recursion, global-variables

I am solving a challenge at HackerRank Recursion:Davis' Staircase.
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-recursive-staircase/problem?isFullScreen=true&h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=recursion-backtracking

There is time limitations. the code that cannot pass time limitation is :

```
def stepPerms(n):
    memo={1:1,2:2,3:4}
 
    if n in memo:
        return memo[n]
    else:
        memo[n]=stepPerms(n-1)+stepPerms(n-2)+stepPerms(n-3)
       
    return memo[n]
```

and the code that can pass the time limitation is:

```
memo={1:1,2:2,3:4}
def stepPerms(n):
    
 
    if n in memo:
        return memo[n]
    else:
        memo[n]=stepPerms(n-1)+stepPerms(n-2)+stepPerms(n-3)
       
    return memo[n]
```

The only difference is where I put memo={1:1,2:2,3:4}, inside of the function or outside of the function as global variable. Can somebody help by pointing out the reason?

Comment: Of course it does. If you put the definition inside the function, a *new dictionary is created each time the function is called*, hence the memoization becomes useless.

Comment: Note the canonical way to do this is a _decorator_.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you!

Comment: you might want to read about [tail recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion). TLDR: this problem is solvable with a single loop, without recursion